# Dynamic code in Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to make a query to this table in my Repo:

```
 user_id | create_author | delete_author | update_author | read_author
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     |   true        |    false      |    false      |   true
```

In my code, I get the column's name as a string (e.g. `variable = "create_author"`). How can I insert `variable` into my query?

When I have hardcoded `create_author` it does work:

```
def auth() do
    App.Permission
    |> where(user_id: ^Map.get(current_user, :id))
    |> where(read_author: true)
    |> Repo.one()
    |> case do
      nil -> false
      _user -> true
    end
end
```

I want to be able to enter a `variable = "read_author"` or `variable = :read_author`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `field` expression for this:

```
def auth() do
  variable = :read_author
  App.Permission
  |> where(user_id: ^Map.get(current_user, :id))
  |> where([p], field(p, ^variable) == true) # <- this
  |> Repo.one()
  |> case do
    nil -> false
    _user -> true
  end
end
```

If you have a string, you can convert it to an atom using `String.to_existing_atom/1` or `String.to_atom/1`.

Comment: Would not `|> is_nil() |> Kernel.!` be cleaner in the tail?